# Set Data Roaming on/off in an iPhone through code

Tags: iphone, roaming

I would like to be able to to switch roaming on or off from my app but haven't found much about it, is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with non-jailbroken devices.

Comment: I thought so after not finding anything.. thank you very much for the answer.